# Different output in Arduino versus normal C compiler

Tags: c, encryption, arduino, block

I'm currently implementing the Misty Block Cipher on Arduino IDE, and I'm facing a weird issue. Bear in mind that I'm far from a competent coder. I took the code from a github page, and compiled in on an online C compiler and it works perfectly fine, but in Arduino the output is super messed up. I attempted to debug both codes and printing different states in the code, and I know where it messes up.

```
    void misty1_encrypt(unsigned int *expkey, unsigned char *ptext,
    unsigned char *ctext)
 {
 unsigned int D0, D1;
 int i, j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) EK[i] = expkey[i];

D0 = D1 = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    D0 = D0 << 8;
    D0 |= ptext[j++];
}
printf("D0 atm:");
printf("%02x",D0);
printf("\n");
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    D1 = D1 << 8;
    D1 |= ptext[j++];
}

printf("D1 atm:");
printf("%02x",D1);
printf("\n");
}
```

Printing the above code in the C Compiler its gives

```
    old plaintext1 : 0123456789abcdef
    D0 atm:1234567     
    D1 atm:89abcdef
```

However, when printing the code in Arduino, this is what I get

```
    old plaintext1 : 0123456789abcdef
    D0 atm:4567
    D1 atm:cdef
```

I don't want to post the whole code so it doesn't take 20 pages, but it's worth mentioning that I'm implementing this based on the RFC2994 Implementation and can be found here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2994

From my minor coding knowledge I feel that the issue may arise from the use of Unsigned Int, but I used Uint_32t, and the same output resulted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry in advance if the post is a bit convuluted, I'll try my best to answer any questions that might help.

Comment: *Arduino* is a programming environment. What *processor architecture* are you targeting? I would suggest, like you said, using `<stdint.h>` types, like `uint32_t` everywhere that the specific size matters.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Hey! Thanks for the quick reply, I'm using Arduino Uno R3 along with the basic Arduino IDE if that answers your question. And yes, I did attempt to covert each unsigned int used in the original code to uint'x'_t (x being 8, 16 or 32 where applicable), but no luck. I have been going around in circles for ages; I'm sure you can imagine the frustration.

Comment: Arduino Uno has 16 bit ints. The code appears to be written assuming 32 bit ints.

Comment: @Art Hey! Thanks for the response! That is a pretty good point actually that I didn't realize (I'm new to all this stuff); would you mind telling me what alternatives I can take to covert it somehow from 32 bit ints to 16 bit ints?

Comment: @Omar as you and I both said, use `uint32_t`. Then post a [mcve] with your results.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Hey, I worked on it since I posted this question, I know I didn't post the complete code here, but using uint32_t for all the variables is not feasible on my poor arduino's memory. I think my best bet is to divide these 32 bit ints into two seperate 16 bit ints and concatenate them. I will keep you updated if you're at all interested. Thanks for the feedback though!